# Why selectors don't work, modification ignored and striketrough in @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have some issues with a media query, here is what I wrote

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

    #points_nav li{
        width: 1rem;
        height: 1rem;
    }
}
```

then I added this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and the original css

```
#points_nav li{
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem; 
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0 1rem;


position: relative;

}
```

I did some research and I did all what people said on forums ! but I still don't understand WHY it doesn't work, It's the same selector so it's supposed to change the property but it's still strikethrough. and modifications don't apply.

```
w̶i̶d̶t̶h̶:̶ ̶1̶r̶e̶m̶;̶
h̶e̶i̶g̶h̶t̶:̶ ̶1̶r̶e̶m̶;̶
```

but when i add more precision like

```
#container_div #points_nav li{
        width: 1rem;
        height: 1rem;
    }
```

it works.
And i don't know why but it actually seems randomly works, sometimes it doesn't (I might be wrong though). Thanks for your help !

Comment: ["The `only` keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the given styles. *It has no effect on modern browsers.*"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: *'It's the same selector'* -- But it's *not* the same selector..

Comment: So... in the original CSS you're targeting `#points_nav a` but in the media query you're targeting `#points_nav li` ....

Comment: sorry i edited it , my bad ! @RobertC

Comment: @Phiter yes i understand that, on original CSS it perfectly works , so why on media queries the poperty is just ignored with the same selectors

Comment: @Blazemonger i changed it , it didn't change anything

Comment: Is the `@media` query before or after the non-media query in the CSS file?

Comment: i guess it is before , its constructed like that 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CV2css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CV2css2.css">
and my media is in CV2.css after the body{..} style , is that correct ?

Comment: @Curt thanks it was basically that , i have to put it at the very end , thank you  ! you can post an answer , and then i will mark it as the solution and upvote . Thanks !

Comment: `@media` does not modify the specificity, especially it does **not** make any rule inside more specific.

Comment: My goodness -- It's bad enough to style based on ids, but _two_ ids! Please stop!

Comment: @Curt Oh what a cascading piece of style sheet. Good catch!

Comment: @JakeParis it's unique, so i use id , what is the point to use class here ?

Comment: @DoupDoup No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wrote it in that order, the reason is clear:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

    #points_nav li{
        width: 1rem;
        height: 1rem;
    }
}

#points_nav li{
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem; 
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here the width settings of the media query is overwritten by the regular CSS rule. They both have the same selector, so the settings in the second rule will overwrite the settings in the first one. To avoid that, you can reverse the order.

If you instead start with this in the media query above

```
#container_div #points_nav li{
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

...and then add

```
#points_nav li{
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem; 
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

..., it will not be overwritten, since the selector `#container_div #points_nav li` has a higher *specifity* than just `#points_nav li`. To overwrite a CSS rule, the following rule needs to have at least the same specifity.